# Defining arrays in CUE and exporting to OpenAPI

Tags: openapi, cuelang

For the following simple CUE code which defines a `match` object containing two team names (as an array of two strings) and the score of the match (as an array of two integers):

```
#match: {
    id: int
    teams: 2 * [string]
    score: 2 * [int]
}
```

when I run `cue export --out openapi test.cue` (with CUE v0.4.0), I get the error messages:

```
components.schemas.match.properties.score.default.0: incomplete value int
components.schemas.match.properties.score.default.1: incomplete value int
components.schemas.match.properties.teams.default.0: incomplete value string
components.schemas.match.properties.teams.default.1: incomplete value string
```

If I change `string` to `string | *null`, it works - however I don't really see why the elements of an array need to have a default value in order to be exported as OpenAPI (especially since there is no such requirement for object properties)? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this looks to be an inconsistency with OpenAPI and incomplete values. The workaround is to specify default elements.

```
import "list"

#s: string | *null
#match: {
    id: int
    teams: [#s, #s]
    score: list.Repeat([int | *null], 2)
}
```

Note, the way I wrote `team` and `score` here result in slightly different, but equivalent, schemas.

On an aside, math operators have been deprecated. You should use [list.Repeat](https://pkg.go.dev/cuelang.org/go/pkg/list#Repeat) instead for that portion. You can also list out the elements if you desire.

For more details, see https://github.com/cue-lang/cue/discussions/1115